# Redis won't install with Resque Task

Tags: ruby, redis, rvm, resque

I'm trying to set up Resque with Redis and followed the documentation:

https://github.com/defunkt/resque#section_Installing_Redis

But when I execute 'rake redis:install dtach:install' I get:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'redis:install'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I also tried everything with sudo. I don't know how to resolve this. I suspect there might be something wrong with my ruby setup?

When I type 'sudo bundle install' I get the following:

```
/home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
from /home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
from /home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Seems like there is a seperate ruby and gemlist inside my ruby 1.9.3-p194?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the Redis install task was removed:

https://github.com/defunkt/resque/commit/d17bda1b59857bbcec92bf617ff2d6ac74c78834

That's why the task redis:install obviously won't work.

They should update the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `sudo` with RVM, try plain `bundle install`, `sudo` looses environment variables which are used to configure RVM / Ruby / Rubygems.

also make sure all the steps were successful, especially the `git clone` command

Comment: yeah that's also what I just realized. But I only tried that after trying it without sudo and it didn't work either. And the git clone command was successful. It just doesn't seem to get the redis:install tasks which are supposed to be provided by resque.

Comment: make sure you have this file https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/Rakefile in current directory

Comment: wait, I updated my ruby version, installed bundler through 'gem install bundler' and get 'Successfully installed bundler-1.2.4' and then tried 'bundle install' to install the missing gems. But then I get: 'ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.'

Comment: yeah that was it ... but I still get the same error when I run 'rake redis:install dtach:install' and I have the Rakefile in my folder.

Comment: OMG ... it's probably because of this? https://github.com/defunkt/resque/commit/d17bda1b59857bbcec92bf617ff2d6ac74c78834